# Raspivid multicast UDP streaming

Tags: video, streaming-video, raspivid

I need to stream `raspivid` video via UDP instead TCP in a multicast fashion.

Using:

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -vf -ih -fps 30 -n -o udp://dest_address:12345
```

I can stream the video trough UDP on `dest_address` host where I can play it with:

`vlc udp://@:12345 :demux=h264`... it works fine.

Unluckly I need a server like approach:

1. In the real case I don't know host `dest_address` but I know its network address (and mask and so on) and therefore broadcast address of such net;
2. At least a second host should be allowed to connect and receive the same stream;
3. I need it to be as much realtime as possibile (at least on the first host connected host).

the command line above does not fit my need (`raspivid` will not listen for UDP connections).

I tried using `netcat` in this way:

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -vf -ih -fps 30 -n -o - | nc -lu 12345
```

and then tried to stream it trough `vlc` (tried several urls and command line options) but nothing seems to work.

I previoulsy used `raspivid` and `netcat` to *simulate* a TCP video server in this way

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -vf -ih -fps 30 -n -o - | nc -l -p 12345
```

and it works fine but it only accept a single *client*.

P.S. I'm not an expert in TCP/IP and/or UDP networking (and maybe I should have misunderstood some basic concept) but I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to do this a few times but never gotten the results I wanted.  Just recently I revisited it and found this works to multicast directly from raspivid.

```
raspivid -a 12 -a "ras2" -t 0 -b 3000000 -fps 20 -w 1920 -h 1080 -o udp://239.255.1.2:1234 -ih -fl -stm -if adaptive -pf main -v -n
```

Then use this on a linux PC to view:

```
vlc udp://@239.255.1.2:1234 --demux=h264
```

I was actually very surprised because all the solutions I googled mention streaming through VLC or `netcat` or using `uv4l` instead of `raspivid`.  This exhibits slightly over 1 second latency which is pretty fantastic I think.  I didn't have a second host convenient but I was able to start two instances of VLC on the same host.

The Raspberry Pi I am using is a Pi 2 running stretch and using the native Pi camera.

I can't take credit for any of the above.  It was cobbled together from many many sources found googling and as noted I just for giggles tried outputting to a multicast address.

Comment: I need to check for your solution to work in system but I bet it works fine. Nevertheless it will be unapplyable in my case since I need a much lover latency (not more than 200ms)

Comment: unfortunately none of this works for me. My vlc on the receiving end runs on Windows 10 and doesn't show anything :-(.

Comment: I suggest researching topics about enabling receipt of multicast on winows 10 like this one: "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/a-client-may-not-be-able-to-connect-to-multicast-streams-or-to-other-user-datagram-protocol-streams-through-windows-firewall-by-using-windows-media-player-5f604764-3081-de5c-a522-a0a56e9d0adc"

Comment: Also note the --demux h264 argument is required.